# Why are my items from ListBox disappearing when I close form in C#?

Tags: c#, listbox

Here is the problem: I have Form1 (welcome screen), Form2 (game), Form3 (listbox with words for game). When I add new words and go back to welcome screen or game recently added words (items) disappear. Only default items from collection are always in ListBox.

Language: Visual C#

Here is the code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.TextLength > 3)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(this.textBox1.Text);
            button2.Visible = false;
            textBox1.Visible = false;
            listBox1.Height = 211;
            textBox1.Text = "";
            label1.Visible = false;
        }
        else {

            label1.Visible = true;
        }


        brojreci = listBox1.Items.Count; //number of items in listbox


    }
```

UPDATE:

I got a question about how am I closing the form:

```
this.hide();
```

Comment: How are you closing the Form?

Comment: Standard mistake is using the wrong object reference.  Just set a breakpoint on the constructor, you'll probably get a break twice.  The debugger's Stack Trace window shows you the bad code.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that?